# Git SSH in RStudio works using the GUI button, but not using shell

Tags: git, ssh, rstudio

I have an RStudio project connected to a GitHub repository. I'm using SSH authentication and I can commit, push/pull using RStudio's GUI with no problem. However, when I try pushing using the shell by e.g. `git push` or `git push -u origin master` I get an error

```
Could not create directory 'c/Users/<user>/<path>/<reponame>/=/.ssh'
```

I have checked many related questions, but none of them seems to solve this issue. How come the gui push button achieves the desired result, while the above code fails? If I change authentication to https, I can push/pull using the shell, so it is clear that it has something to do with ssh.

I'm on Win10, using RStudio 1.1.383  and Git 2.8.3.windows.1.

Any ideas?

Comment: `git remote show origin`?

Comment: I get the same error `Could not create directory...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `git config -l` for any SSH related setting.
Check also your environment variable (type 'set' in a CMD, or `env` in a git bash). I would double-check the value of `%HOME%` or `$HOME` in your bash session.

I suspect a variable or configuration with an incorrect value, including an '`=`' in it.

As seen in the comments:

> set `HOME=%USERPROFILE%` changed the HOME path.

Comment: thanks. `git config - l` did not provide any ssh related setting.  `env` gave me tons of stuff, among which `HOME` related are: 
`HOMEDRIVE=C:`
`HOMEPATH=\Users\<user>`
`HOME=/c/Users/<user>/Documents/<path_to_project_folder>/=`

Comment: @sparrow HOME seems to be the issue. Can you set `HOME` to `C:\Users\<user>` (in your environment variables)? Then open a git bash session, confirm that `HOME` is `/c/Users/<user>` and proceed from there. Relaunch RStudio once HOME is properly set.

Comment: That did the trick. `set HOME=%USERPROFILE%` changed the `HOME` path. Although, whenever a new session is started it is reset to the old value.